# Problem with RegisterClientScriptInclude and RegisterClientScriptBlock

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I Have usercontrol and i registered the following javascript method in code behind :

```
changeSelectedMenu(controlID);
```

the previous method is declared in JScript.js file so i registered it also .

but the following exception has been thrown :

```
 Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

The result page is :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/JQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
changeSelectedMenu('ctl00_ctl00_cntMain_procedureContentHolder_procedureMenu_appointmentsLink');//]]>
</script>
```

Is There anyone can help me to workaround this issue???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't valid paths to your JavaScript:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/JQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

They need to be relative to the page or to the site root, for example:

```
<script src="/Scripts/JQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

While `~/` works for resolving a path on the server-side, the browser doesn't know how to handle this.  There are some other work-arounds in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697660/asp-net-master-page-and-file-path-issues) for making it work and still being app-relative.

Comment: I already include javascript files :
<asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/JScript.js" />

Comment: @DEVMBM - According to your question, they're rendering as `~/` in the page, is that not the case?