# Javascript not working from masterpage

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a masterpage and a JS file, I added a link to the javascript file in the master page but on any page that uses the master page the JS isnt working.

I have tried the code on its own in a separate page and it works.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link href="../styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Menu.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function openNewWin(url) {
            var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,left=0,top=0,resizable=no,status=no');
            x.focus();
        }
    </script>



</head>
```

Menu.JS:

```
$(function () {
    //When opening the page all level 2 and level 3 items must be hidden.
    $(function () {
        hideitems();
    })

    function hideitems() {
        $('h10').hide();
        $('h11').hide();
        $('h12').hide();
        $('h13').hide();
    }
    //Financial Click
    $('h7').click(function () {
        hideitems();
            $('h10').slideToggle();
            $('h11').slideToggle();
            $('h12').slideToggle();
        });
    //Container Click
        $('h8').click(function () {
            hideitems();;
            $('h13').slideToggle();
        });
    })
```

Comment: Not working how? any errors?

Comment: FYI: you are adding click handlers inside of click handlers. That's not a great idea.

Comment: No errors but the functionality doesnt work. The menu items should load hidden and then you can modify them by clicking on them but they simply do nothing.

Comment: it's likely a path issue, view source on the page that gets rendered, find the fully path that was created, and cut and paste it into a browser.. if you get 404, you know the path is wrong

Comment: It doesnt create a path in the markup, it is just /Scripts/menu.js

Answer (score 0):

I think it's file path issue.Can you follow the steps given here

[ASP.Net Master Page and File path issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697660/asp-net-master-page-and-file-path-issues)

Comment: I looked at that post already, the when I used the script manager it said it wasnt valid and for the find path it gave an invalid character error.

Answer (score 0):

Is a path issue as said before.

Are you sure the folder is Scripts and not scripts?

open the inspector and get the link is refering, also probably you will get an error in the console