# Trouble after trouble trying to integrate custom Javascript into an ASP.NET webforms app

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I'm in a pickle here....

I'm trying to create a new, pretty much standard ASP.NET Webforms app targetting .NET 4.5.2. I've done it many times before - but never ran into these problems (and can't quite figure out *WHY* they happen now and never before....).

My customer supplied a set of CSS and Javascript as basis for the project, and this includes Bootstrap and jQuery amongst other things.

Now when I'm trying to get my first simple pages to work, I'm running into serious trouble with including some additional Javascript into my page.

**Attempt #1**

I was trying to have my Javascript files included like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Web.MyMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js no-ie">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=$start">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Images/Icons/favicon.ico" />

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/vendors.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeaderContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

That seemed to work - until I deployed to our test environment for the first time. There, the apps are not "rooted", e.g. they're installed in a IIS setup where the path to the app is `http://test.server.com/apps/MyApp` - and now my references to `/Scripts/....` all break and nothing is found

**Attempt #2**

I tried changing the include of the scripts to use the `ResolveUrl()` method I had used before:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/vendors.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>"></script>
```

so in this case, ASP.NET *should* resolve those names based on the app's root directory (no matter where that is) and include those scripts.

Trouble: now I'm getting an error (upon startup) saying something like (freely translated from German):

> The control collection cannot be modified since the control contains code blocks (e.g. <% ... %>)

I beg your pardon?!?!?!?!?!

**Attempt #3**

So my last resort was to use data binding expressions like this:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/vendors.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>"></script>
```

and this requires that I do a

```
Page.Header.DataBind();
```

in the `OnInit` event handler of the master page, and once I do that, when I try to use the DevExpress Grids, I get a nasty error:

> Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request. For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

OK, so I'm at the end of my wisdom - ***HOW*** on earth can I include a few Javascript files into an ASP.NET Webforms app *today*, in 2016, so that *everything just works* - no nasty .NET errors, no Javascript not found....... what's your approach to fix this dilemma of mine??

Comment: Does your page reside in the application root? If it does, you can simply use relative URLs, e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/vendors.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: no, my pages are in several subfolders and subfolders within those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebForms is special when it comes to script tags. One thing you can do is use a [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) as described on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/697674/26226)

Also, attempt #2 would work if you removed `runat="server"` from your `<head>` tag. If you're not accessing the head tag from codebehind, there's no need for it to be a server control.

Or, for a more "modern" approach, the [ASP.NET Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) stuff works in WebForms too. I've used it in a few projects without any issues.

Comment: If I remove the `runat="server"` from the `<head>`, I can no longer set the `Page.Title` property.....

Comment: As for the bundling & minification: *sounds* like a great idea, but I had tons of issues - tried to combine various `*.js` files into a bundle, but when trying to add that bundle (with its "logical" name) to the Script Manager, I kept getting errors about "this needs to have a .js extension" and stuff like that..... never worked for me (yet)

Comment: You should be able to use `<%= Scripts.Render("~/bundle/path") %>`, but then you might have the same issue as Attempt 2 with a server head tag ...