# ASP.Net Master Page and Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I got the following HTML code in my master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="Styles/MasterStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/ShoppingCartSideMenuJavaScript.js") %>"></script>

    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div id="ShoppingCartSideMenu">
            Just some text
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 id="SiteTitle">JEWELRY</h1>
            <p id="UnderSiteTitle">EXCLUSIVE SWISS MADE JEWELRY</p>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Home.aspx">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Shop.aspx">SHOP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About.aspx">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Terms and Conditions.aspx">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact.aspx">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li id="seperator">|
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <a id="ShoppingCartBtn" onclick="ShoppingCartBtn_Click" runat="server">
                                <img class="ShoppingCart" src="/Images/Icons/Shopping_cart.png" />
                                <label id="CountCartItems">0</label>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="FooterWrapper">
                <div id="FooterDiv1">
                    &copy; 2016 JEWELRY - Created by someone
                </div>
                <div id="FooterDiv2">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img id="FooterFacebook" class="Icons" alt="Facebook" src="/Images/Icons/facebook-logo.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img id="FooterTwitter" class="Icons" alt="Twitter" src="/Images/Icons/twitter-logo.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img id="FooterInstagram" class="Icons" alt="Instagram" src="/Images/Icons/instagram-logo.png" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I got this Javascript in a separate js file

```
var main = function () {
    /* Push menu over by 350px over */
    $('#ShoppingCartBtn').click(function () {
        $('#ShoppingCartSideMenu').animate({
            right: "0px"
        }, 200);
    });

    /* Then push the menu back */
    $('body').click(function () {
        $('#ShoppingCartSideMenu').animate({
            right: "-350px"
        }, 200);
    });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

I tried every way suggested in this post: [ASP.Net Master Page and File path issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697660/asp-net-master-page-and-file-path-issues)

But nothing seems to work

Comment: what the problem here ?

Comment: `ShoppingCartSideMenuJavaScript.js` is not loaded?

Comment: `#ShoppingCartSideMenu` is already set with `right:-350px` the javascript suppose to move it to `right:0px` when i click the image i have there `#ShoppingCartBtn`, but when i click, nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ResolveUrl instead and create url from the root like this.

```
Page.ResolveUrl ("~/Scripts/ShoppingCartSideMenuJavaScript.js")
```

**Update**: That means you have not referenced jQuery.js before using it. Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("path/to/jquery.js") %>"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/ShoppingCartSideMenuJavaScript.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: on your master page, you are calling the script, change the script src there

Comment: ohh, sorry, ok... tried it, still not working, nothing happen

Comment: are your sure your js file is in the Scripts/file_nmae.js and the file resides in the root? also check for typos

Comment: yeah, 1 million percent sure :(

Comment: are you seeing 404 in console?

Comment: console says: ShoppingCartSideMenuJavaScript.js:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined...
what is that mean?

Comment: reference jquery in your head before using it.