# Path translation in asp.net masterpage

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

In Site.Master page, I have references to a few CSS and JS files.
When a page in a subfolder uses this master page, I can see that the css file's path gets correctly translated, by adding necessary ../ in front of it, but not for JS files which results in 404 errors when viewed in Chrome's debug window.

I tired using ~ with runat=server to force translation; didn't work; tried using Page.ResolveURL that gives no error message but seems to break the script and not sure how I can this to work.

In Site.Master:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This gets correctly displayed as the following for a .aspx page that is in a sub-folder:

```
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

for JS files, none of the following works.

This one shows just as is for the same file in sub-folder:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="assets/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This one shows no 404 erro; a "/<sitename>/" gets prepended to path but script does not work (e.g. drop down menu does not drop)

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/assets/scripts/bootstrap.min.js") %>'></script>
```

And this one, I don't think I can do this!

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script runat="server" src="~/assets/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697660/asp-net-master-page-and-file-path-issues). The post offers a few options but what was listed as Edit2 of the answer was what worked for me:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/assets/scripts/jquery.js") %>' ></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/assets/scripts/bootstrap.min.js") %>' ></script>
```